# What is the maximum speed of EOS?

Tags: eosjs

What is the maximum transaction speed for EOS?
I read that 100,000 transactions per second. But I'm not sure about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:

Single threaded performance: up to 8,000 TPS

Multi-threaded performance: unlimited TPS

---

Here's what Dan Larimer said at the launch of Dawn 3.0

https://medium.com/eosio/eosio-dawn-3-0-now-available-49a3b99242d7

> ## Performance
>
> Real-world performance is something our team has been monitoring
> closely, and we are very happy with the results at this time. We have
> benchmarked our software in several different configurations to
> understand the lower and upper bound of performance as we enable
> future optimizations. All of these tests are assuming token transfers
> to be apples-to-apples comparable to Bitcoin or Ethereum ERC20 token
> transfers in terms of computational complexity.
>
> ### Worst Case — 1000 TPS
>
> This is our baseline performance without any optimizations. We are
> able to sustain over 1000 TPS using a multi-node network running the
> interpreter with single-threaded signature verification.
>
> ### Average Case — 3000 TPS
>
> Once we turn on the JIT compiler we can sustain 3000 TPS using a
> multi-node network running the interpreter with single-threaded
> signature verification.
>
> ### Best Case — 6,000 TPS
>
> Once we implement parallel signature verification, we can assume the
> wall-clock-time per-signature will approach 0 as the level of
> parallelism and the number of signatures increase. We can simulate
> this environment by disabling signature verification. Under this model
> we can hit 6,000 TPS on a multi-node network with the JIT compiler.
>
> ### Theoretical Case — 8,000 TPS
>
> If we remove the networking code from the equation and focus only on
> what the CPU is capable of doing with signature verification turned
> off and using the JIT, then we can hit 8,000 single-threaded
> transactions-per-second. To go higher than this on a single chain
> would require implementing parallel execution of the WebAssembly, and
> a more advanced scheduler. In this same scenario, using the
> interpreter rather than the JIT, we can see 2700 TPS. This suggests
> that the relatively simple change of enabling the JIT will give us
> about 3x performance increase for transfers. These measurements were
> made on a MacBook 2.8Ghz i7.
>
> ### Unlimited Transactions Per Second
>
> The definition of a “transaction per second” is often an apples to
> oranges comparison. With inter blockchain communication we can divide
> the workload between as many blockchains as we want. Tokens can
> reliably and securely be transferred between different chains. With
> 1000 chains operated in parallel by the same (or different) block
> producers we could see millions of transactions per second. This
> represents a practical realization of the theoretical scaling
> proposals presented by other blockchains.

I think there is more to a blockchain performance other than TPS.
For example block production intervals, time to reach irreversible block, etc...